# Django does not redirect to "Next" after custom login when login is required

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

When I use the login view provided by Django, it redirects to the desired page after login. My code is as follows:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from admn import views as views
from django.contrib.auth import views as log_views
urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', log_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
        path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def  profile(request):
    return render (request, 'profile.html')
```

However, when I use a customized login, it logs in but does not redirect the initial page. My code is as follows:

**urls.py**

```
from admn import views as views
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', views.login, name='administration-login'),
        path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from myforms import UserLoginForm
from django.contrib import messages

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            dj_login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f'You are logged in {username}!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'Not logged in')
    else: 
        form = UserLoginForm()
    return render (request, 'login.html',{'form':form})

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def  profile(request):
    return render (request, 'profile.html')
```

Comment: You can see the code in `LoginView` that handles the redirect in the [`get_redirect_url`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/40a64dd1e24d45f8e00a55b22a5174b8f1359b5c/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L69) method, (which is called by `get_success_url`). After calling `dj_login`, you should redirect to the next URL (at the moment, the view continues so you render the `login.html` template again). However, I recommend using Django's `LoginView` instead of writing your own. If you need to customize the behaviour, then subclass it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the

> LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = profile

in setting.py file?

Comment: No, because it is set here @login_required(login_url='/login/') and it worked with the django login view.

Comment: could you please trying doing it and test it? Because the @login_required decorator just indicates that for reaching to this view needs login